# MongoDB - query unknown field in the middle of a full path

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

What is the right way to implement a query with unknown field in the middle of a full path (such as use **asterisk** in the query to get the values 'passed' for all countries on a specific date)?
for example : "countries_info.*.1_1_2018.allEvents.passed"?

When I use elasticsearch I am able to add asterisk in the middle of the query string but how do I do it in MongoDB?

Thanks

consider next object :

```
{
"countries_info": [
        {"country_name": {
                "1_1_2018": {
                    "allEvents": {
                        "passed": 5,
                        "fails": 2
                    },
                    "city_1_events": {
                        "passed": 2,
                        "fails": 0
                    },
                    "city_2_events": {
                        "passed": 3,
                        "fails": 2
                    }
                },
                "1_2_2018": {
                        "allEvents": {
                            "passed": 4,
                            "fails": 2
                        },
                        "city_1_events": {
                            "passed": 2,
                            "fails": 1
                        },
                        "city_2_events": {
                            "passed": 2,
                            "fails": 0
                        }
                    },
                "all_dates": {
                        "allEvents": {
                            "passed": 9,
                            "fails": 4
                        },
                        "city_1_events": {
                            "passed": 4,
                            "fails": 1
                        },
                        "city_2_events": {
                            "passed": 5,
                            "fails": 3
                        }
                    }
            }},
            {"all_countries": {
                "1_1_2018": {
                    "allEvents": {
                        "passed": 5,
                        "fails": 2
                    },
                    "city_1_events": {
                        "passed": 2,
                        "fails": 0
                    },
                    "city_2_events": {
                        "passed": 3,
                        "fails": 2
                    }
                },
                "1_2_2018": {
                        "allEvents": {
                            "passed": 4,
                            "fails": 2
                        },
                        "city_1_events": {
                            "passed": 2,
                            "fails": 1
                        },
                        "city_2_events": {
                            "passed": 2,
                            "fails": 0
                        }
                    },
                "all_dates": {
                        "allEvents": {
                            "passed": 9,
                            "fails": 4
                        },
                        "city_1_events": {
                            "passed": 4,
                            "fails": 1
                        },
                        "city_2_events": {
                            "passed": 5,
                            "fails": 3
                        }
                    }
            }}
            ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/#exp._S_objectToArray) which converts an object to an array of elements `{k: <key name>, v: <value>}`, so you can ignore the `k` and use the `v` only. In your particular case the pipeline can be like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$countries_info" },
    { $project: { 
        _id:0, 
        countries_info: { $arrayElemAt: [ {$objectToArray: "$countries_info"}, 0 ] } 
    } },    
    { $project: { passed: "$countries_info.v.1_1_2018.allEvents.passed" } }
])
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @Alex Blex. arrayElemAt is available from version 3.4 and I use older version. I will need to use some other solution

Comment: First of all it's objectToArray that's available from v3.4, arrayElemAt is available from v3.2. Secondly, "older" is not a version really. Which one you aim? For generic "older" version the only option is map-reduce. As a side note v3.0 reaches end of life next month, and v3.2 does it, a half-year later.